# Probability game - Simulation don't match the manual solution

Tags: r, probability, monte-carlo

**Two numbers are bring chosen by random from the set {1,2,3,4,5}. If the sum of the two numbers is even, you win 100 dollars, otherwise you win nothing. In order to participate in the game, you pay $80. What is the expected value and variance of the profit after 17 games ?**

I solved this one analytically and with Monte Carlo simulation and got different results, I wonder where my mistake it.

*My Solution:*

The probability of success in one round is:

$p=\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{0}+\binom{2}{0}\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{5}{2}}=0.6$

The number of successes is:

$X:Bin(17,0.6)$

Therefore:

$E(X)=10.2 , V(X)=4.08$

The profit is defined as:

$Y=100X-1360$

And thus:

$E(Y)=-340 , V(Y)=40800$

My R code is below, and it yields different results , e.g.:

$E(Y)=-480.38 , V(Y)=42751.21$

The differences are too big in my opinion, so there must be a mistake somewhere.

Can you assist me identifying the mistake ?

```
n = 5000
successes = rep(0,n)
for (j in 1:n)
{
  result = rep(0,17)
  for (i in 1:17)
  {
    game.result = sample(1:5,2,replace = T)
    if (sum(game.result)%%2==0)
    {
      result = 1
    }
  }
  successes[j] = sum(result)
}

successes
mean(successes)
var(successes)

profit = 100*successes-1360
mean(profit)
var(profit)
```

Comment: If you are sampling with replacement, then the probability of success is 13/25, not .6

Comment: Your solution assumes sampling without replacement, the code assumes sampling with replacement. You're also setting your entire `result` vector to 1s on an even result, due to writing `result = 1` instead of `result[i] = 1`.

Comment: Also your monte carlo simulation code is wrong.  Successes is not summing the results over the 17 attempts

Comment: If you're sampling without replacement, check your calculations of the success probability. Hint: It's not $0.6$.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from your question whether you are sampling with or without replacement.  In the former case the probability of winning is $p_*=0.52$ and in the latter case the probability of winning is $p_{**}=0.40$.  (As an exercise, try to derive these probabilities from your problem.)  Consequently, the distribution of the profit and its mean and variance under either scenario is:

$$\begin{matrix}
\ \ \pi_* \sim 100 \cdot \text{Bin}(17, 0.52) - 80*17
& & & \ \mathbb{E}(\pi_*) = -476
& & & \ \mathbb{V}(\pi_*) = 42432, \\[6pt]
\pi_{**} \sim 100 \cdot \text{Bin}(17, 0.40) - 80*17
& & & \mathbb{E}(\pi_{**}) = -680
& & & \mathbb{V}(\pi_{**}) = 40800. \\[6pt]
\end{matrix}$$

Both of these results can easily be confirmed by simulation.  In `R` we can use the [`sample.int`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sample) function to directly sample from the set under consideration.  Here I will construct a function to simulate the profit for this kind of problem.  For generality I will take the specific values in your game and set them as default inputs that allow alternative specification in the function.

```
#Create function to simulate the profit
simulate.profit <- function(sims, games = 17, 
                            objects = 5, draws = 2, replace = FALSE,
                            cost = 80, winnings = 100) {
  
  #Determine outcomes of games and profit
  WIN    <- matrix(FALSE, nrow = sims, ncol = games)
  PROFIT <- rep(0, sims)
  for (i in 1:sims) {
    for (j in 1:games) {
      SAMPLE   <- sample.int(objects , size = draws, replace = replace)
      WIN[i,j] <- (sum(SAMPLE) %% 2 == 0) } 
    PROFIT[i] <- winnings*sum(WIN[i,]) - games*cost }
  
  #Return profit simulations
  PROFIT }
```

Using this function we can easily simulate the profit values under either sampling-with-replacement or sampling-without-replacement.  The simulations below confirm the means and variances calculated above.

```
#Simulate using sampling-without-replacement
set.seed(1)
SIMS <- 10^7
PROFIT.SIMS1 <- simulate.profit(sims = SIMS, replace = TRUE)

#Compute the mean
mean(PROFIT.SIMS1)
[1] -476.0598

#Compute the variance
var(PROFIT.SIMS1)
[1] 42432.42

###########################################################
#Simulate using sampling-with-replacement
set.seed(1)
SIMS <- 10^7
PROFIT.SIMS2 <- simulate.profit(sims = SIMS)

#Compute the mean
mean(PROFIT.SIMS2)
[1] -680.0054

#Compute the variance
var(PROFIT.SIMS2)
[1] 40802
```

Answer (score 1):

As others noticed, you made few mistakes in your assumptions and the code. In your simulation you sample with replacement. The description of the problem says nothing about drawing without replacement, so it's up to you how you read it. In such a case, the probability $p$ is

```r
# list all the possibilities
outcomes <- matrix(NA, 5, 5)
for (i in 1:5) {
    for (j in 1:5) {
        outcomes[i,j] <- i + j
    }
}
# how many there are?
m <- prod(dim(outcomes))
# how many are winning?
k <- sum(outcomes %% 2 == 0)
p <- k / m
## 13 / 25 = 0.52

n <- 17
(n * p * 100) - (17 * 80)
## -476
```

Also there are bugs in your code. When writing a simulation code, it is usually a good idea to make it as simple as possible, so that it literally matches the problem. In such a case, you have the lowest risk of incorrect results due to the bug.

```r
sim <- function() {
    profit <- 0
    for (i in 1:17) {
        outcome <- sample(1:5, 2, replace = T)
        profit <- profit - 80
        if (sum(outcome) %% 2 == 0) {
            profit <- profit + 100
        }
    }
    return(profit)
}

result <- replicate(50000, sim())

summary(result)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
## -1360.0  -660.0  -460.0  -475.2  -360.0   340.0 
var(result)
## 42469.426952539
```

of using more high-level simulation:

```r
result <- (rbinom(50000, size=n, prob=p) * 100) - (17 * 80)

summary(result)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
## -1260.0  -660.0  -460.0  -476.4  -360.0   340.0 
var(result)
## 42303.3516630333
```

As you can see, they match.

Comment: Thank you ! You are correct, as the other guys too. I have wrote replace = T instead of F. Silly mistake. My calculation is also wrong. p is not 0.6, but it ain't 0.52 either, it is 0.4. I have changed it to 0.4 and now the results are much closer. Is my formula for p correct ? I think that my calculation using calculator was faulty

Comment: @BlueSigma as you can see above, the probability is calculated as the number of winning outcomes divided by the number possible outcomes. This is exact enumeration.